# Behaviour of the conj() function on arrays

Tags: arrays, julia, complex-numbers

The current Julia version in use is 1.1.

I am having problems understanding why the application of the conj() function to a complex array does not yield an error. (It should only work on scalars as far as I understand). The same is true for the real() and imag() functions.

I am currently learning Julia and try to understand if this is an inconsistency in the language syntax or a misunderstanding on my side.

```
ek = exp.(collect(range(0, length=10, stop=pi))*im)
ek_t = conj(ek)
```

This does not yield an error and gives me the correct complex conjugation. I would have expected only the following piece of code to work (which also works):

```
ek_t = conj.(ek)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that there is no need for `collect` (there very rarely is.) Also, check out the `cis` function: `ek = cis.(range(0, π, length=10))` Now there's only one allocation instead of three.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question.  In short, it's because we treat arrays as not only collections of values, but also as mathematical quantities themselves.  A good example is how you can multiply two matrices with either matrix or element-wise multiplication:

```
julia> A, B = [1 2; 3 4], [10 20; 30 40]
([1 2; 3 4], [10 20; 30 40])

julia> A * B
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
  70  100
 150  220

julia> A .* B
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 10   40
 90  160
```

Just like how matrices can be multiplied like they're mathematical quantities, matrices themselves can be conjugated.  It just so happens that the answer is the same as the element-wise computation, but it's no less valid.  You will see some advantages to using `conj.(...)` if it can fuse with other dot operations.

A good source here is the professor of mathematics who pushed back on our attempt to deprecate these functions alongside many other deprecations: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/18495#issuecomment-267215901